# Find fails with "Too Many Arguments" in Shell Script, but not if run directly in a Terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, shell-script, find, launchd

I have a work station that stores images temporarily before compressed versions are uploaded to a server for safe keeping. I have an interest in deleting old files once a day at 3 AM using a script scheduled via launchd.

```
#!/bin/bash
find /some/directory/with/pictures/* -exec rm -rf {} \+
```

I have verified this to work on a development workstation with only about ~250 mb of images (30 images).

Since the production workstations haven't had this script running, they have **a lot** of images, on the order of several hundred gigabytes. This means that when `find` is executed via the shell script, it stops and says "Too Many Arguments."

I spent a lot of time trying to figure out why (trying xargs, seeing if changing `+` to `;` affected anything... etc) the only thing I didn't try was actually going into the directory via the shell script to avoid using find altogether. I think the "Too Many Arguments" makes sense - it sounds like there's a cap on number of arguments, and I have ~33,000 files in the one workstation I'm proving this concept on.

To confuse things for me even more, executing `find ./ -exec rm -rf {} \;` within the directory itself via the Terminal works (slowly).

I've performed the delete using the Terminal so I'm not worried about the process in the future (it won't produce anywhere near 33k pictures in a day), but what I want to know is **why** `find` works in the Terminal with 33k arguments, but not within a shell script.

Comment: Your script and what you execute in the directory are not exactly the same, the `*` in your script might be triggering a shell expansion which could overflow a command line length limit.

Comment: Would changing the shell script line to `find ./some/directory/with/pictures/ -exec rm -rf {} \+` be equivalent? I had trouble with earlier iterations where I'd delete the folder containing the files as well.

Edit: It is not equivalent. It deletes the folder as I expected.

Comment: @Nestarion Try `find ./some/directory/with/pictures/ -mindepth 1 -exec rm -rf {} \+` (on a test directory, of course). The `-mindepth 1` should prevent it from deleting the directory itself.

Comment: `find ./some/directory/with/pictures/` doesn't work, but removing the period does work when I added `-mindepth 1` as you proposed. But this question was more about why and how `find` is limited rather than the syntax of my command (though it is related).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've run into the *nix "[too many files open](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1449787)" issue! Macos has limits on how many files a process, and the system can open at a time. This is much the same as how `ulimit` interacts with Init on most Linux systems.

These limits are set separately for the terminal and for filesystem-based applications. The default limits of each process are inherited from launchd on macs (since Leopard or so), and you can see them as-compiled using `sudo launchctl limit`

There are ways to change this behevior, such as [How to persistently control maximum system resource consumption on Mac?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/108174/how-to-persistently-control-maximum-system-resource-consumption-on-mac), and [Which command controls the open file limits?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/33715/which-command-controls-the-open-file-limits)

Comment: The links you provided are immensely helpful. This is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: -1. In this case `find` doesn't even open files resulting from the expansion of `*`; it just confirms they exist, this action requires reading directory entries. The tool opens directories though (if any), but it does this one by one: it closes one before opening the next. `rm` also doesn't open files, it unlinks them one by one. "Too Many Arguments" is not "Too Many Open Files".

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski According to `man find` on my system find _"GNU find
       searches the directory tree rooted at each given starting-point by
       evaluating the given expression from left to right, according to the
       rules of precedence (see section OPERATORS), until the outcome is
       known (the left hand side is false for and operations, true for or),
       at which point find moves on to the next file name."_ Meaning that the entire tree from the base dir is _open_ during the command's run (to some definition of the word _open_).

Comment: @cawwot `find` doesn't need to open files to search *directory trees*. No part of the OP's command actually opens a file that has been found. The executables (`find`, `rm`) need to be opened with some additional files maybe (like libraries, locale, …), but that's it.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski In a forked filesystem file _descriptors_ get opened by commands like `find`, `rm`, etc. Macs use HFS (or HFS+ on newer macs), have what Apple calls [Resource forks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_fork), which are opened by file system commands, one for each file (generally).

Comment: You're getting closer to convincing me your answer may be right. Still I seriously doubt `find` or `rm` (or the filesystem driver) needs to keep so many descriptors open at the same time so it hits the limit. Sane tools would open and close them in sequence, (almost) one by one. Are you saying Macs with HFS/HFS+ are prone to resource depletion during such a basic operation like traversing a directory tree or removing a bunch of files?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski 1/2 looking specifically at [rm](https://github.com/openbsd/src/blob/master/bin/rm/rm.c) we can see that it uses {OPEN_MAX} from [limits.h](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/limits.h.html) to respect "Maximum number of files that one process can have open at any one time".

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski 2/2 However, [find](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/fs/ubifs/find.c) has no such limit, and it only limited by max heap size and max_int. Specifically we can see in the function ubifs_find_free_space (starting at line 493) that a file descriptor is opened for every _match_ to the `find` criteria (this is how the files get matched to your `find` criteria, after all). OPs issue is most likely that they hit the max size in number of matches.

Comment: I'm not a programmer but: (A) I cannot find `OPEN_MAX` in `rm.c` you link to. (B) this `find.c` is a part of [UBIFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UBIFS). I don't know why it should matter in the context of `find(1)` and HFS.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski ah, you're right, I saw limits.h and I assumed. However, looking at `rm`'s rm_tree func (starting line 131), it never builds a tree, it just walks it item by item. This is in comparison to find (from [findutils](https://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/findutils/), which is the package included on macos I'm pretty sure, I had linked to the wrong find before). tree.c ingests the entire tree, stat-ing on each file as it gets it, this would, unless I'm terribly mistaken, open an each file and dir's resource fork in an inode until it had finished ingesting, walking, and optimizing the tree.

Comment: Again, I'm not a programmer but: (C) The very first line of `tree.c` says `tree.c -- helper functions to build and evaluate the expression tree`. Expression tree organizes operands, not files/directories. (D) Mac uses BSD `find` by default. I believe you can install GNU utilities on demand though.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I'm not 100% sure, I'm not a programmer either, and I don't have a mac right now to see in person. However, it seems to me that BSD `find` is doing more or less the same thing, but instead of building a tree it runs chains of comparison executors (giving a comparable behavior in terms of files being opened). I am open to being proven wrong, this just 'feels' like what is happening here to me.